# How to check specific column exist in datarow?

Tags: asp.net

I came across situation,where columnname for datatable is dynamic.While fetching a data I want to check existence of column.

```
DataTable table = ds.Table["Sample1"]

if(table.Row.Count > 0)
{
foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows )
{
    if(dr.Table.Column.Contain("DateInfo"))
    {
        // store value in variable
        // first approach
    }

    if(table.Column.Contain("DateInfo"))
    {
        // store value in variable
        // second approach
    }
}
}
```

Which one is best approach?

Comment: It needs to be `Columns.Contains` instead of `Column.Contain`

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADO.NET DataRow - check for column existence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970985/ado-net-datarow-check-for-column-existence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this be enough:

1st Approach: Which will simply check in an entire DataTable.

```
datatable.Columns.Contains("column")
```

2nd Approach: which will check for each row collection in DataTable

```
dr.Table.Columns.Contains("column")
```

3rd Approach: Which fetch each columns in DataColumnCollection object and then check if it contains the specific field or not.

```
DataColumnCollection columns = datatable.Columns;

if (columns.Contains(columnName))
```

So these all approaches are better in their own way. you can use whatever you find it better.

Answer (score 1):

This is best one

```
dr.Table.Column.Contain("DateInfo")
```

foreach loop get single row at a time sometimes if any conditional is possible in this method